# facebook graph api special calls, js

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I am trying to find some user information from a user. However, I can only get those which are in public_profile and "simple types" like first_name, gender etc. However, I cannot get age_range, or user_relationships status or current locations. I am using the snippet,

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,first_name,last_name,email,birthday,age_range'}, 
       function(response) { 
           ...});
```

everytime I try getting the age_range, it just says [object Object]. But I can get the name and birthday just fine. How should I fix this. 
My entire code:-

```
function checkLoginState() {
FB.login(function (response) {
 if (response.status == 'connected') {
  FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,first_name,last_name,email,birthday,age_range'},
   function(response){
     document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =response.first_name+
       ' '+ response.last_name+ ' ' + response.email+ ' ' +response.birthday+ ' ' +
       response.age_range;
    });
    }, { scope: "public_profile,email" });
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: People who are down voting this, please give me a reason without just randomly voting. Or else how can someone know where they went wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

age_range is an object, it looks like this in the result:

```
"age_range": {
   "min": 21
},
```

Try with `console.log(response.age_range.min)`, for example.

Not sure what you mean with the other things, you are not even asking for the hometown or other stuff.

Comment: Sorry, hometown is my main priority but i was also trying with age_range and got the same thing. I shall try what you said. @luschin

Comment: well, as i said, you don´t even ask for hometown...you really need to learn how to debug javascript stuff. if you can´t figure out what to do with an object, you are pretty helpless ;)